# Runtime error in UVA Online Judge, Problem 839, Python

Tags: python

**Problem**

The program takes input that has information on mobiles (the kind that consists of wires and strings supsending weights). The program should check if the mobile is in equilibrium, that is the weight of the mobile is equal on both sides. Done by this equation **weightLeft * distanceLeft = weightRight * distanceRight**. However one mobiles weight on one side can be the result of another subMobile hanging below. So in the example that will be shown there is a whole "tree" of mobiles connected to one antoher.
More specific explanation here: https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=780

**Example input**

First line consists of how many testcases are to follow. Each line contaning numbers is a description of a mobile according to this templete (weightLeft, distanceLeft, weightRight, distanceLeft). If there is a zero on the weight value then the weight is the total weight of a submobile below. If a mobile has two zeros then both the weights come from different mobiles on the following lines, first the left then the right always.

```
5

0 2 0 4
0 3 0 1
1 2 1 1
2 4 4 2
1 6 3 2

0 2 0 4
0 3 0 1
2 1 1 1
2 4 4 2
1 6 3 2

0 2 0 4
0 3 0 1
1 1 1 1
2 4 4 2
1 6 3 2

0 2 0 4
0 3 0 1
1 1 1 1
2 4 4 2
1 6 3 2

0 2 0 4
0 3 0 1
1 1 1 1
2 4 4 2
1 6 3 2
```

**My Code**

My code is below and it does work acording to the input i typed my self according to the description (i think). No error, nothing wrong. But when i submit it to the online judge, it fails. I get a runtime error and a have no idea why. Anyone who could help my out would be much appreciated.

```
testcases = int(input())
input()
equal = True


def begin():
    global equal
    input_data = input().split()

    left_side = int(input_data[0])
    right_side = int(input_data[2])

    if input_data[0] == '0':
        left_side = begin()

    if input_data[2] == '0':
        right_side = begin()

    if (left_side * int(input_data[1])) != (right_side * int(input_data[3])):
        equal = False

    return left_side + right_side


for x in range(testcases):
    equal = True
    begin()

    if equal:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print("NO")
    print("")
    input()
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Answer**

After trying and playing around with the input i noticed that the program was reading input and printing at the end of the testcase **no matter what**. This caused problems at the end of the input because the very last row of the porgram reads input when there is no more input. So after making these changes to the code, i got the program accepted by the UVA Judge

```
for x in range(testcases):
equal = True
begin()

if equal:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
if not x == (testcases -1):
    print()
    input()
```